# custom name attributes for form_for helper in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am using geocomplete plugin to auto complete address form in my form.

Geocomplete only recognizes form fields with a set name attribute, such as

```
  <input name="lat" class="lat" type="text" value="">
  <label>Longitude</label>
  <input name="lng" class="lng" type="text" value="">
  <label>GPS</label>
  <input name="location" type="text" value="">
```

other wise, it wont be able to find the field in a given form to complete.

below is the form in rails 4

```
<%= form_for(@property, :url => landlord_properties_path(current_landlord)) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group selection property type">
      <%= f.text_field :name,class: "geocomplete" %>
      <%= f.text_field :lng,class: "lng" %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :lat,class: "lng" %>
      <%= f.submit "add" %>
<% end %>
```

however the generated HTML has nested attibutes like

```
<input class="lng" id="property_lng" name="property[lng]" type="text">
```

which has the property added to the attribute, so geocomplete wont be able to find the form.

how do customize the name attribute to

```
name ="lng"
```

and still send the attribute to the current @property object and pass it into the controller?

EDIT

so the solution is to add `'name'=>'lng'` to the text field, this works great!

however, now the attribute don't get past the strong parameter

here is the property_params

```
def property_params
   params.require(:property).permit(:name,:lat,:lng)
end
```

and here is the what gets passed into the form parameter

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uXfT7XUZBuedbfAj8OaDMT673txmk379BM5PENQBRsk=", "property"=>{"name"=>"100 Kent Street, Ottawa, ON, Canada", "lat"=>""}, "lng"=>"-75.70343909999997", "commit"=>"add", "dependent"=>:destroy, "landlord_id"=>"1"}
```

it seems like property is a hash containing the values, but lng is now a seperate thing outside of the property hash, so it doesnt get written into the db

how do i set custom parameter to let lng into the property controller object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to f.text_field:

```
'name'=>"lng"
```

Comment: how would i let that attribute into my strong parameters?

Comment: Try this :name => 'lng' instead 'name' => 'lng'